# Send date to wcf rest service

Tags: javascript, .net

I am calling wcf rest service from javascript through jquery ajax call and my service body style is bare. For some reason I cannot add body style wrapped. I want to send the date parameter to service. Please some body help.

Comment: What do you mean by `service body style`?  Can you provide an example of the data currently being returned by the service, and what you'd like it to return?

Comment: Below is the example                                                                     [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/GetContents/{ID}")]
        List<Content> GetContents(DateTime date, string ID);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether its best solution, but solved it by using Class with class member DateTime . i.e

```
Class SampleClass{
    private DateTime _sampleDate;
    public DateTime SampleDate
    {
        get
            {
                return _sampleDate;
            }
            set
            {
                _sampleDate= value;
            }
    }

}
```

Used the above obejct to pass the date.